# responsive 2 col grid with equal margin

Tags: html, css, grid

By using **only percentage**, how to create equal margin that fit into a specified container? I tried below but failed to achieve equal margin.

```css
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#000;
}
.category_wrap div {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want equal margin in both side you should have 1% margin in right as well. What is your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vcoekymx/1/)**

```
.category_wrap div:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

And I also added `48.5%` width on `div` column to compensate the margin.

`48.5` comes from (100-3)/2 where 3 is the overall percentage of left/right margins per one row.

Another option would be to wrap it in the `container`, give it a width of `98%` and give `margin: 0 1%;` to it and then give odd `div` column a `margin-right: 1%`;

Answer (score 0):

Add media query in css to slove your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of the exact effect you are seeking, but @knitevision is right on by using an nth-child selector in CSS to balance the margin down the middle of the column with the margin on the left and right side of the container div.

Here it is in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chuddayo/pen/ZbXYRq)

HTML:

```
<div class="category_wrap">
    <div class="container">1</div>
    <div class="container">2</div>
    <div class="container">3</div>
    <div class="container">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}
.category_wrap div{
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 48.5%;
  height: 50px;
}
.container:nth-child(odd){
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 .5% 0 1%;
}
.container:nth-child(even){
  margin: 0 1% 0 .5%;
}
```

Like @knitevision's answer, If you are seeking a 1% margin down the three gutters, 48.5% becomes the magic number for each div's width: (100-3)/2.

Also, be careful with using % margins in height parameters as 1% height does not equal 1% of the width and your margins will look off.

Further Reading:
[How nth-child Works](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score 0):

```
box-sizing: border-box is the best way to do this. It changes the width and height to include the padding and border.The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.
```

Fiddle Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/ckvpc0to/

```
                <div class="category_wrap">
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
                <div>5</div>
                <div>6</div>
                <div>7</div>
                <div>8</div>
            </div>
```

---

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#000;
}

.category_wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.category_wrap div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
     padding: 10px;
border:2px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```